# Syncing Multiple WaveSurfer Playheads

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

I have dropdown with two modes, one is solo mode and one is unison. When unison mode is selected I want multiple wavesurfer objects to have their playheads synced. There is an original wavesurfer and several other wavesurfers that should move to the same progress state as the original.

I tried using the following code, but when I moved the playhead for the original wavesurfer, the others did not move.

> /**
> handle unison button function
> */
> handleUnison(playPauseButton) {
> let waveSurferList = this.getWavesurferList();
> let originalWavesurfer = waveSurferList.shift();
> if (originalWavesurfer.isPlaying()) {
> playPauseButton.children[0].style.display = "";
> playPauseButton.children[1].style.display = "none";
> else {
> playPauseButton.children[0].style.display = "none";
> playPauseButton.children[1].style.display = "";
> }
> originalWavesurfer.seekTo(
> originalWavesurfer.getCurrentTime() / originalWavesurfer.getDuration()
> );
> originalWavesurfer.playPause();
> waveSurferList.forEach((waveItem) => {
> waveItem.playPause();
> });
> this.syncWaveSurfers();
> }

> /**
> Synchronize all WaveSurfer instances when in unison mode.
> */
> syncWaveSurfers() {
> let waveSurferList = this.getWavesurferList();
>
> Find the reference waveSurfer (the first one)
> let referenceWaveSurfer = waveSurferList.shift();
>
> Listen for the "seek" event on the reference WaveSurfer
> referenceWaveSurfer.on("seek", function (progress) {
> Update the playheads of other WaveSurfers
> waveSurferList.forEach((waveSurfer) => {
> Ensure that we don't trigger an infinite loop by ignoring the reference waveSurfer
> if (waveSurfer !== referenceWaveSurfer) {
> waveSurfer.seekTo(0);
> }
> });
> });
> }